# How to include .class files from dependency project maven?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, maven-jar-plugin

I have two maven projects:

1. This is the framework project and has the dependency classes in the src/main/java
2. This is the project that contains my test scripts in the src/test/java

I want to build a jar where both the class files are included from the project in the 2nd project's pom.xml file.

What type of plugin can do the job? I have tried using maven jar plugin and assembly plugin but neither of them solved my problem.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you want to achieve. Classes in `src/test/java` are not packaged into jars. They are purely to run tests during the build.

Comment: what exactly you are trying to achieve? post more informatin.   mazbe your pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

Both your tests and your main classes should be included in the same project, not separately. A test suite should not be a separate "module" that is imported as a dependency via `pom.xml`. Just as [@J Fabian Meier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/927493/j-fabian-meier) pointed out - the tests are not included in your output file when compiled - they are just there to be ran while building to test your classes.

It's very unclear what you're trying to achieve. You might want to go through how a [standard Maven project directory layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) should look like.